# Retrieve data from dynamically generated form

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a dynamically created form to edit content on a page. I retrieve information from a DB table (in this case image captions) and display them in text areas ready to be edited and saved back into the DB.

This seems to do the job of organizing and displaying the form:

```
echo"<form action='edit.php' method='post'>";
 for ($limit;$limit<=$all_values;$limit++)
     {
      echo "<textarea cols='15' rows='3' name='caption' value='$caption_arr[$limit]'>
             $caption_arr[$limit]</textarea><br>
      }
      echo "<br><input type='submit' value='Edit' name='pictureEedit'></form>";
```

But something goes wrong from here. When I enter this in edit.php:

```
 $caption=$_POST['caption'];
 echo $caption;
```

And I only get the caption from the last field. When I added check boxes to the form it all worked fine provided I only checked 1 but if I checked 2 or more it would only give me the value for the last one.

I also tried this:

```
 $caption[$x]=$_POST['caption'];
 foreach ($caption as $key => $value) {echo $key.$value.'<br>';}
```

but got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form

```
name='caption'
```

has to be

```
name='caption[]'
```

And later on you can do:

```
foreach ($_POST['caption'] as $key => $value) {echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br>';}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. Is there a way I can also just update the fields that have been saved? Say I have 1000 images and captions in a gallery and a use only edits 1 caption would it make sense to let my script update ALL the captions? Or is there a way to make it only chaenge the one that's been edited?

Comment: Then you have to find out, which ones really changed. So you have to read in all items shown in your form, and when submitted check against the $_POST values.

Comment: Would I have to re-query the DB in my edit.php page just to compare the  entries? Or could I maybe add a hidden form field with the original caption so I can do a comparison in edit.php?

Comment: Yes, you can add a hidden fields like name="value_orig[]" AND then compare all $_POST[<key>]['value_edit'] versus $_POST[<key>]['value_orig']. Anyway, I am not a friend of hidden fields - Never show user output, he does not really need. So I'd better go with reading it in again. (MHO)

Comment: What do you mean by that? When finished I'll redirect the user to the page he came from with all the changes applied. How would he see stuff in hidden fields?

Comment: This is more a security aspect. I can see hidden fields in the source code. Perhaps in your case the user can't do anything threatening with them. Anyway, I prefer not to show the user any hidden fields and always check against values (from database or session) he can't see/access/change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same name for all fields. you have to make array of them. try this

```
 name='caption[]'
```