# Retrieve data in PHP from a dynamically created form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using Javascript to dynamically create input fields in a form. Like, if the user inputs 3, my script should create 3 input fields having their name attributes as Member 1, Member 2 and Member 3.How do I set a name attribute to such elements using DOM ? And how do I access data from these fields in PHP using post method ?

Here is my sample code.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addFields(){
        var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "Member"+i;
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
       }
    }   
</script>
</head>

<body>




<form action="create.php" method="post">
    <h2>Create Document :</h2>


    Document Description :<input type="text" name="document_description" >
    Number of members: (max. 10)<input type="text" id="member" name="number_of_receipents" value=""><br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <input type="button" value="Fill Details" name="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" button="submit">
    <div id="container"/>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve data from dynamically generated form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122755/retrieve-data-from-dynamically-generated-form)

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122755/retrieve-data-from-dynamically-generated-form

Comment: Also, check this as the elements disappear immediately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263414/dom-element-disappearing-immediately-after-update

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming them `Memberx` name them as `Member[]`,

Then `$_POST['Member']` will return an array of all the submitted values

```
array (size=1)
  'Member' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Value1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Value 2' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Value3' (length=6)
```

Code use in the example:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="Member[]" />
<input type="text" name="Member[]" />
<input type="text" name="Member[]" />
<button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```